# Why do arrays in .net only implement IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, ienumerable, ienumerator

I was implementing my own ArrayList class and was left surprised when I realised that

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return _array.GetEnumerator();
}
```

didn't work. What is the reason arrays don't implement IEnumerator in .NET?

Is there any work-around?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you implement your own ArrayList class when there are already over a dozen existing collection classes?

Comment: Why wouldn't I? I'm tired of those kinds of comments.

Comment: We don't ask these kind of questions to annoy you, but to find out what it is you are trying to do. This helps us supplying you with a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I am implementing an ArrayList because although all languages have some sort of ArrayList provided in its framework, I assumed .NET didn't have one. Thanks guys for clearing it up.

Comment: @devouredelysium, .NET has a `List` class, which is the equivalent of the Java `ArrayList`. I think it's generally better to re-use built-in types than create your own.

Comment: These kind of questions are annoying though, because they seek to divert the conversation and the answers away from what is being asked. I always find it's better to answer what was asked no matter how silly it "seems".

Comment: I see reasonable justification on both sides of the argument.  After reading the original question and before reading this subthread, I hypothesized that he may have been implementing it either for practice or maybe for an assignment.  Asking the "why implement your own" question did lead to some clarification about C#'s List vs Java's ArrayList, though.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Arrays do implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but it is done as part of the special knowledge the CLI has for arrays. This works as if it were an explicit implementation (but isn't: it is done at runtime). Many tools will not show this implementation, this is described in the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7#remarks) section of the `Array` class overview.

You could add a cast:

```
return ((IEnumerable<T>)_array).GetEnumerator();
```

Note, older MSDN (pre learn.microsoft.com) coverage of this changed a few times with different .NET versions, check for the [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) section.

Comment: It works just as if the "class" `T[]` implemented `IEnumerable<T>` by an _explicit interface implementation_. If you simply say `_array.GetEnumerator()` you get instead the `public` method which has the wrong return type.

Comment: @RayL See the .NET 2.0 version of the documentation :-) updating.

Comment: Just a heads up. From the referenced https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx#Remarks: it implements `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces.

Answer (score -2):

You can use generic method `IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>()` from System.Linq namespace, which extends IEnumerable interface. It will filter out all elements which type is different than T and return `IEnumerable<T> collection`. If you use `(IEnumerable<T>)_array` conversion operator, it might not be safe, because `System.Array` (and other nongeneric types) stores items of type `System.Object`.

Comment: Only arrays of Objects (i.e. `Object[] arr`) stores the item as an object. Other than those, array's are type safe.   That makes the OfType and Cast methods redundant.