# Array class and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I have 2 questions about the following code:

```
 IEnumerable<int> arr = new int[] { 2, 17, 4, 6 };
 Console.WriteLine(arr.GetType());
```

The output is:

```
 System.Int32[]
```

1. What is the class of "arr" variable? is it Array class? Does Array class equal every XXX[]?
2. if arr is from Array class, how is it successfully converted to IEnumerable(int) interface? I see that Array implements only IEnumerable, but not IEnumerable(T)

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of questions why cast does not change type of object and how array implements enumerable...

Comment: Look at `new int[]`. Obviously, *arr* is an instance of `int[]`, which is special "auto-generated" type which implements these interfaces thanks to the CLR.

Comment: @Dave That's not true. If `Car : Vehicule` and `Bus : Vehicule`, a `Bus` cannot be stored as a `Car`

Comment: Looks very similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773740/why-do-arrays-in-net-only-implement-ienumerable-and-not-ienumerablet

Comment: @IllidanS4, does this special generated type "int[]" inherit from Array?

Comment: @Jaxx Yes, it can be confirmed with reflection or the fact that you can cast it to *Array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The type is System.Int32[]. <strike>Yes, this is an instance of the Array class.</strike> Edit: See Hans' comment below.
2. From the documentation of Array Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`<T`>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`<T`>, and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`<T`> generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and as a result,
>   the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the
>   Array class

Comment: The Array class is abstract, you can never create an instance of it.  Review Type.MakeArrayType() to get insight in how the CLR dynamically creates array types.