# Is the C# Programming Guide right on pretending that arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I recently answered this question on Code Review: [Exists Method Implementation for Multidimensional Array in C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257366/9810). The question is about determining whether an array of arbitrary dimension contains a specific element.

Based on this statement found in [Arrays (C# Programming Guide) / Array overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview):

> Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Since this type implements IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>, you can use foreach iteration on all arrays in C#.

and given the declaration `int[,,,] array4`, I first gave the answer:

```cs
bool result = array4.Any(x => x == 1);
```

However, according to a comment of @JimmyHu, the compiler generates a:

> Error  CS1061  'int[*,*,*,*]' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'int[*,*,*,*]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Apparently, the correct answer must be:

```cs
bool result = array4.Cast<int>().Any(x => x == 1);
```

This other attempt

```cs
bool result2 = ((IEnumerable<int>)array4).Any(x => x == 1);
```

does not work either and yields:

> Error  CS0030  Cannot convert type 'int[*,*,*,*]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'

**Question**: is the C# Programming Guide wrong on this point or I am missing something. Do arrays derive from `Array` which implement the generic interface or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do C# multidimensional arrays not implement IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275073/why-do-c-sharp-multidimensional-arrays-not-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: Does this answer the question about the programming guide? Even Jon Skeet says: *" it seems pretty weird to me"*.

Comment: The guide is an over-simplification -- only single-dimensional arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: it kinda does answer it. the guide claims _all_ arrays implement IEnumerable _and_ IEnumerable<T>, whereas the answer says _multidimensional_arrays only implement IEnumerable. so yes, technically the guide is wrong - or at least imprecise.

Comment: It looks like the [bottom few comments of this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13010) discuss this

Comment: I posted this as a new issue on github: [Text unclear about arrays implementing IEnumerable<T> #23399](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/23399).

Comment: I think that's unnecessary -- it was already mentioned in the issue I linked, and I added a comment linking to your SO post

Comment: They're actually both wrong, even a single-dimension vector array does not implement it. It is implemented for 1-dim arrays by a class called `SZArrayHelper`, which is magically hacked into the array's method table. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/aa97964558672440.html also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773740/why-do-arrays-in-net-only-implement-ienumerable-and-not-ienumerablet So it *appears* that it can be cast to `IEnumerable<T>` but in fact it is SZArrayHelper implementing it.

Comment: The [Array overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview) of the docs has been [fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/23399) back in April 2021.